# How to add column with query folding using snowflake connector

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to add a new column to a power query result that is the result of subtracting one column from another. according to the power bi documentation basic arithmetic is supported with query folding but for some reason it is showing a failure to query fold. I also tried simply adding a column populated with the number 1 and it still was not working. Is there some trick to getting query folding a new column to work on snowflake? [image]

Answer (score 1):

If the computation is made based only on data from source, then it could be computed during table import as SQL Statement:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col1 + col2 AS computed_total
FROM my_table_name
```

[image]

---

EDIT:

> The problem with this solution is that native SQL statement for snowflake is only supported on PBI desktop and I want to have this stored in a dataflow (so pbi web client) for reusability and other reasons.

Option 1:

Create a view istead of table at source:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view
AS
SELECT col1, col2, col1 + col2 AS computed_total
FROM my_table_name;
```

Option 2:

Add computed column to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table_name
ADD COLUMN computed_total NUMBER(38,4) AS (col1 + col2);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that native SQL statement for snowflake is only supported on PBI desktop and I want to have this stored in a dataflow  (so pbi web client) for reusability and other reasons. Thank you anyway for your answer

Comment: @Lawton Fair enough, provided alternative appoaches that could be added on source level(i.e., view or computed/virtual column

Comment: Those are other options I have in mind